# Responsive Nav bar toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a relative newbie to web design who has been working on a personal project\training for about 4 months to help me learn.

I have got deeper and deeper into this and have spent weeks trying to make the desktop web site that I have done responsive. However I am struggling to get my 'mobile' toggle bar working as it should and have searched and searched but cannot find an answer to my problem. I have tried different approaches but to no avail.

Basically with what I have at the moment the Hamburger keeps dropping to the bottom of menu instead of staying in place within the Nav bar. If I set this to absolute, which seems to solve this problem, then I cannot get this positioned properly in the Nav bar.

Also I have also been trying to get the Hamburger to slide in from the left and fill about 70% of the screen with the hamburger sliding across to the right, again to no avail. Whatever approach doesn't seem to work and all I can get is a dropdown. I suspect there is something going on with my messed up code that I don't understand. As as a newbie I have been trying to incorporate what I have read as best practice and realise some of my code may be long winded and a bit of a miss mash so any tips on how to clean it up would be much appreciated.

The general idea of what I have been trying to achieve is this: http://www.ymc.ch/sandbox/hamburger/mobile-menu-demo.html

I have stripped the code back to the basics, as whatever I am trying isn't working, and this is a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pr3tr3y2/4/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="nav">
<div class ="navWrapper">
<nav role="navigation" class="menu">
    <ul class="active">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li>
        <a href="MainPage.aspx">Menu 3</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>  
        <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 4</a>   
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="hamburgerWrapper">
          <div class="toggle-nav"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</div> 

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Javascript/JavaScript.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(UndoHTML.css);

#container
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
        text-align:center;
}

/*For mobile phones*/
/*NAVIGATION MENUS*/
.nav
{
    background-color: black;
}

.navWrapper
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    /*box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);*/
}

/*HORIZONTAL MENU*/
.menu
{
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
}

.menu ul.active 
{
    display:none;
}

.menu ul li
{
    position: relative;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b3c4e6;
}

.menu ul li a
{
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display:block;
    color: #fff;
    padding:16px 16px 12px 16px;
    border-bottom:5px solid transparent;
}

.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #7EF300;
    color: #FFDB00;
}

/*HAMBURGER*/
.hamburgerWrapper
{
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    padding: 10px;
}

.toggle-nav
{
    background: linear-gradient(
        to bottom, 
        #FFF 0%, #FFF 20%, 
        transparent 20%, transparent 40%, 
        #FFF 40%, #FFF 60%, 
        transparent 60%, transparent 80%, 
        #FFF 80%, #FFF 100%);
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 24px;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
    width: 32px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}

.toggle-nav a
{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

/*Sub Menu*/
.menu ul li:hover ul 
{
    display: none;
}

.submenu
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: black;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.submenu > li > a
{
    text-align: left;
    /*border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display:block;
    color: #fff;
    padding:7px 16px 5px 16px;
    border-bottom:5px solid transparent; /*To offset white underline hover*/
}

.submenu > li:hover > a
{
  background-color:red;
  color: #FFDB00;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #7EF300;
}

#contentLayer 
{
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 30%;
    z-index: 5;
}

/*Medium Screens*/
 @media all and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 999px)
{
    .toggle-nav 
    {
    display:none;
    }

    .hamburgerWrapper
    {
    display: none;
    }

    .navWrapper
    {
    justify-content: center;
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
    }

    .menu
    {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
    }

    .menu ul.active 
    {
    display:flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .menu ul li
    {
    border-bottom: none;
    }

    .menu ul li:last-of-type
    {
        margin:0;
    }

    .menu ul li:hover ul 
    {
        display: block;
    }
}

/*Large Screens*/
@media all and (min-width: 1000px)
{
    .navWrapper
    {
    max-width: 1366px;
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
    }

    .toggle-nav 
    {
    display:none;
    }

    .hamburgerWrapper
    {
    display: none;
    }

    .menu
    {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
    }

    .menu ul.active 
    {
    display:flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .menu ul li
    {
    border-bottom: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .menu ul li:hover ul 
    {
    display: block;
    }
}
```

JQUERY:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('.toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
          jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
          jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');

          e.preventDefault();
      });
  });
```

Comment: this might be usefull to you https://github.com/purgeru/mmenu-Bootstrap-3

Comment: Sorry I am trying to learn this without using anything like Bootstrap as I want to learn from the ground up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use CSS to animate your menu. The navigation slides on mobile devices and the class `.active` is added on clicking the button instead of when the DOM loads.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
      jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
      jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');
      jQuery('.menu').toggleClass('active');
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

```css
@import url(UndoHTML.css);
//[TO] new code
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/*For mobile phones*/


/*NAVIGATION MENUS*/

.nav {
  background-color: black;
}

.navWrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.hamburgerWrapper{
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  background:#000;
  width: 100%;
}
.active .hamburgerWrapper{
  left: 200px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

/*HORIZONTAL MENU*/

.menu {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: -70%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  background:#000;
  top:0;
}

.menu ul.active {
  left: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b3c4e6;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 16px 16px 12px 16px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #7EF300;
  color: #FFDB00;
}


/*HAMBURGER*/

.hamburgerWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 10px;
}

.toggle-nav {
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, #FFF 0%, #FFF 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 40%, #FFF 40%, #FFF 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 80%, #FFF 80%, #FFF 100%);
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 24px;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
  width: 32px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.toggle-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}


/*Sub Menu*/

.menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: none;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.submenu > li > a {
  text-align: left;
  /*border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 7px 16px 5px 16px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  /*To offset white underline hover*/
}

.submenu > li:hover > a {
  background-color: red;
  color: #FFDB00;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #7EF300;
}

#contentLayer {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 30%;
  z-index: 5;
}


/*Medium Screens*/

@media all and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 999px) {
  .toggle-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .hamburgerWrapper {
    display: none;
  }
  .navWrapper {
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .menu {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu ul.active {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .menu ul li {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .menu ul li:last-of-type {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
}


/*Large Screens*/

@media all and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .navWrapper {
    max-width: 1366px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .toggle-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .hamburgerWrapper {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu ul.active {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .menu ul li {
    border-bottom: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="navWrapper">
      <nav role="navigation" class="menu">
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="MainPage.aspx">Menu 3</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="hamburgerWrapper">
          <div class="toggle-nav"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thomas.

Comment: Not a problem. I hope it helped.

Comment: Sorry Thomas I added that before I finished replying. Sorry for the delay in getting back, I have been trying hard to get this working as best I could before replying. I can see this sort of working with Fiddle but it doesn't seem to work properly for me when I apply it to my site. For some reason I have to swap the settings for the Left .menu ul.active (so it is -70px) and menu.ul elements (so it is 0) so that it works right . It seems wrong and the opposite of what it should be but doesn't give me the desired effect otherwise and the menu is visible without clicking on the Toggle otherwise.

Comment: Just to add I managed to get this all working okay. Your answer was a great help and with a little tweaking managed to get things working as I wanted. The problem in my previous comment was caused by me having a duplicate .menu ul.active in my CSS. Thanks again.

Comment: Not a problem. I am happy you were able to get it up and running. I noticed that the width of the window was hitting a wider media query which had conflicting changes. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Damo,
Your code is working you just have this piece of HTML:

```
<div class="hamburgerWrapper">
      <div class="toggle-nav"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>
</div>
```

At the bottom of the page. Move it up to the top, like so:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="nav">
<div class ="navWrapper">
<nav role="navigation" class="menu">
    <div class="hamburgerWrapper">
       <div class="toggle-nav"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="active">
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li>
    <a href="MainPage.aspx">Menu 3</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>  
    <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 4</a>   
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then it should work.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks John for the reply. Yes this certainly fixes the issue of the Hamburger keep dropping to the bottom of menu instead of staying in place within the Nav bar.  Sorry for the delay in replying but I have been trying to get this work in conjunction with getting the menu to slide in from the left and fill about 70% of the screen with the hamburger then sliding across to the right.